sqflite database gets locked after I hot-restart app
So basically this is my table when I input data:

And then this data is cleared somehow and database is cleared:

I have no clue why this is happening and what to do.
I checked all of my code and sometimes in database inspector I don't see the database at all. I'm guessing that the tables were deleted somehow and were recreated.

Youy have a function that's named deleteDatabaseFile and are calling it.  My guess is that deletes the database file.  Which would delete all the data in it

Please share code for identify issue.
